# Get me a SQL quesry to check whether the two table data contents are equal?

Tags: sql, database

I am having two table A and B of same structure.Both tables is loaded with data.I just want the mismatched row of two tables.,,

Comment: have you tried anything? If you have, please post your attempt (we can help you taking that starting point). If you haven't tried anything, then why should any of us help you? Please read this article: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: One advice based on your previous question (that was also massively downvoted before it got closed) : I think you need to do some reading on the basics of databases before asking about specific topics like this one.  You're not going to be able to cobble enough knowledge about databases together by doing that, some actual study will be required!

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain you could do some gigantic `JOIN` query for each column and then issue a `NOT IN` over the result but a simple, pragmatic solution is to:

1. Write a query that orders the data on several columns (or all)
2. Export the query executed on each table to a separate text file
3. Use `diff` to compare the files with each other

Depending on the RDBMS vendor you may have other options you could consider as well.

Comment: Get me simple query for this scenario..Consider a Table A has column x & column y..Table B has column 1 & column 2..

Comment: @aravindderajan This is not a "do-my-job" site, but a place where you can ask specific questions. Read a good book on databases, try to solve your problems, and if you get stuck in the solution, ask a specific question.